# How to transfer Data automaticly between MySql and Sql Server back and fourth?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I need to build a procedure to read data from SQL Server and insert it into MySql. More I also need another procedure to read data from MySql Server and insert it into SQL Server.

I never done such a thing. I can't think of a way to get it done. Can someone tell me how can I do so such a thing?

I appreciate at least an idea where I can search it.

I have been googling this but did not find much of help.

I have Scribe software I am not sure if there is a future in Scribe that can help me with this?

Note this procedure Will be automatically run so transfer data or receive data from the source.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is to create a [Linked Server](http://www.packtpub.com/article/mysql-linked-server-on-sql-server-2008) in SQL Server, this way you can query both SQL Server and MySQL from the same place. You can write a stored procedure to access both or a Job to run on specific schedule.

**Update:** Sample INSERT Query

```
INSERT OPENQUERY (SERVNAME, 'SELECT subject, notes FROM cms.mysql_table') 
SELECT subject, notes FROM sql_server_table
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have Linked Server already established and I do use OPENQUERY to pull data but How do I use it to insert the data that I pulled into a different server?  I think using open query I can pull data from mysql and then insert it into SQL but how to I do it the other way around?

Comment: It should be very similar, if your select query is something like `select * from openquery(MYSQLSRV, 'select * from table')`, your insert query will be something like `INSERT OPENQUERY (MYSQLSRV, 'SELECT field FROM table')
  VALUES ('my value');`

Comment: I am trying to get the insert to work by reading data from SQL Server into MySql but I can't get this to work. this is what I have done, can you please look into my syntax       SELECT subject, notes FROM sql_server_table AS s
INSERT OPENQUERY (SERVNAME, 'INSERT INTO cms.mysql_table(subject,notes)') VALUES (s.subject, s.notes)

Comment: I've updated my answer with the sample INSERT query, could u give it a try?

Comment: It did not work. I get and error with this message at the end  The user did not have permission to write to the column.

Comment: Make sure your linked server permission allows writing to the DB/Table/Column for that user. It looks like currently it's a read-only permission

Comment: Where do I change the permission from? the linked server? the mysql user has full permission unless the linked server does not have a write permission I don't know whereto change that from

Comment: You need to map remote user to local one:

`EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 
  @rmtsrvname=N'SERVNAME',
  @useself=N'False',
  @locallogin= <your local login>,
  @rmtuser= <remote user>,
  @rmtpassword= <remote password>`

Comment: FYI: The like server is already established. I can read data but I am unable to write. Any way I followed your instruction and I have run that query but I am still having the same issue I can't write data

Comment: So something is still linked incorrectly. Verify that your MySQL user can write to that table and if so - that it is properly mapped to the currently logged user of SQL Server. The error means that the query is correct and attempt to write is made and denied

Comment: the mysql user can write for sure because I am using the same user to my php script and it is the same user i use to login my phpmyadmin and i can read/write/delete with it. Does the local user need a write permissions?

Comment: Okay I found the issue, it is not a permission issue it is conversion issue  the notes column in the MySQL table is of a type text when I change it to Char 255 it works but that not a good solution as I cant change my MySQL column type. this is my working qurty after changeing the text column to char    --INSERT DATA INTO MySql Table
INSERT OPENQUERY (SERVNAME, 'SELECT subject, notes FROM call_managment_system.test') 
SELECT CAST(subject AS CHAR) AS subject,  CAST(notes AS CHAR) AS notes FROM #temp_lasweb

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below to achieve your result

```
SELECT * 
INTO dbo.Users_Import 
FROM OPENQUERY(remotelinkedservername, ‘SELECT * FROM dbo.Users’ )
```

([source](http://sqlserverplanet.com/tsql/using-openquery))